# Ionic3 OneSignal How to check if app is launched because of a notification open event

Tags: push-notification, ionic3, onesignal

I would like to know if there is a way to find out if an app is launched because of a notification opened event.

Currently when a user taps on an incoming notification, OneSignal will resume/launch my application and it will call the handleNotificationOpened handler of the app where I can process the notification without any problems as well as redirect the user to specific page in my app based on the notification's payload.

The issue that I want to solve is that if my application is not running, then OneSignal will launch the app and it will show the default root page of my app for less than a second and then the user will be redirected to the proper page. What I would like to achieve is to prevent showing the app's root page and only show the notification handling page upon clicking on the notification, thus I need to know if there is a way to identify the fact that the app was launched because of a notification tap.

Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your main component and other relevant code

Comment: @Sébastien The question has to do with identifying the way the app was launched i.e. because of user interaction directly through the launcher or by a push notification tapping that will eventually call the handleNotificationOpened handler function. I want to believe that there must be some kind of "injection" into the platform or some other variable that instructs the app to call the handleNotificationOpened function after the app is launched. This is what I'm after, thus my main component or any other code is completely irrelevant since this is not a bug but rather a question of guidance.

Comment: "The issue that I want to solve is that if my application is not running, then OneSignal will launch the app and it will show the default root page of my app for less than a second and then the user will be redirected to the proper page. " what's going on there? Is what I was wondering.

Comment: @Sébastien thanks for your interest but probably I wasn't clear in the question! I want to know if there is something set while the application is launched to indicate that handleNotificationOpened will be called as a result of a push notification tapping. The issue I described has to do with the "flickering" that occurs prior the user is redirected to the required page because of handleNotificationOpened execution.

Answer (score 1):

As I wasn't able to find a way to check launch parameters or anything like that to verify that the application was launched for processing a notification tap I tried tackling the problem from another angle.

For anyone interested in a possible "workaround" I have posted a possible solution. Please do not assume this is a definite solution but rather treat it as a suggestion and by no means do not push this onto your production environment without exhaustive testing.

```
constructor (platform: Platform, private statusBar: StatusBar, private oneSignal: OneSignal) {

var isNotification = false;

platform.ready().then(() => {

  this.statusBar.styleDefault();

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (! isNotification) {
      this.rootPage = FirstRunPage;
    } 
  },3000);

 var iosSettings = {
    kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false,
    kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: false
  };

  this.oneSignal.startInit('replace with Onesignal id');

  this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);

  this.oneSignal.iOSSettings(iosSettings); 

  this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((data) => {
    isNotification = true;
    this.nav.push("NotifyHandlerPage");
  });

  this.oneSignal.endInit();
});
}
```